Wireguard over cloak: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
I encountering the error connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions when trying to use WireGuard over Cloak on Windows, even though WireGuard alone and Cloak with OpenVPN work fine?
Context:
I have setup wireguard and cloak in aws server
Issue: The error occurs when attempting to establish a connection using WireGuard over Cloak on Windows.
Observations:
WireGuard alone works without issues.
Cloak with OpenVPN also works without issues.
The same WireGuard + Cloak configuration works fine on Linux.
Cloak is being run with administrator privileges on Windows.
Troubleshooting Information:
Running netstat -aon | findstr :443 shows multiple established connections on port 443.
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=udp indicates an excluded port range from 50000 to 50059 for UDP.
Cloak is using using port 443
I have even tried to changing port of wireguard to 1196 but still same error
this seems like a windows specifying error, any way to fix
thankyou in advance
wireguard config:
    [Interface]
PrivateKey = *****
Address = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1
MTU = 1300

[Peer]
PublicKey = ******
PresharedKey = *******
Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:1984
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/2, 64.0.0.0/8, 65.0.0.0/22, 65.0.4.0/23, 65.0.6.0/25, 65.0.6.128/26, 65.0.6.192/29, 65.0.6.201/32, 65.0.6.202/31, 65.0.6.204/30, 65.0.6.208/28, 65.0.6.224/27, 65.0.7.0/24, 65.0.8.0/21, 65.0.16.0/20, 65.0.32.0/19, 65.0.64.0/18, 65.0.128.0/17, 65.1.0.0/16, 65.2.0.0/15, 65.4.0.0/14, 65.8.0.0/13, 65.16.0.0/12, 65.32.0.0/11, 65.64.0.0/10, 65.128.0.0/9, 66.0.0.0/7, 68.0.0.0/6, 72.0.0.0/5, 80.0.0.0/4, 96.0.0.0/3, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/0

running cloak:(in windows cmd runed as administrator )
.\ck-client.exe -s 65.0.*.** -u -c .\wireg_udp.json

the full Claok log:
    .\ck-client.exe -s 65.0.**.** -u -c .\wireg_udp.json
time="2024-11-15T19:50:10+05:30" level=info msg="Starting standalone mode"
time="2024-11-15T19:50:10+05:30" level=info msg="Listening on UDP 127.0.0.1:1984 for wireg_udp client"
time="2024-11-15T19:50:13+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting to start a new session"
time="2024-11-15T19:50:13+05:30" level=error msg="Failed to establish new connections to remote: dial tcp 65.0.**.**:443: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."
time="2024-11-15T19:50:13+05:30" level=error msg="Failed to establish new connections to remote: dial tcp 65.0.**.**:443: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."
time="2024-11-15T19:50:13+05:30" level=error msg="Failed to establish new connections to remote: dial tcp 65.0.**.**:443: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."
time="2024-11-15T19:50:13+05:30" level=error msg="Failed to establish new connections to remote: dial tcp 65.0.**.**:443: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

